# How do i display all records from connected groups

Tags: php, mysql, database

My Tables

```
GROUPS
----------
id | groupName
4    Personal
5    Friends
6    University


Records
----------
id | groupId  | name
1    4          Majid
2    4          Jawad
3    5          Zain
4    5          Mohsin
5    6          Ismail
7    6          Zubair


groups_connected
--------------------
id   |  parent_id  |  child_id
1       4             5
2       5             6
```

This is my table structure, i want to display each groups contacts and its parents contacts in php.
for example. when view group 5 Friends, i want to get records of groupId 5 and its parent groups records too.
and also when someone wants to view group 6 University. result should be of university group, Friends group, and Personal group 
if the group is not associated with any group then only that groups records would display.

Comment: I gave you a -1 and a flag for deletion because of your writing quality.

Comment: Apologies for poor writing. its my 2nd question here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `GROUPS` and `Records` twice with different alias names.

Try this:

```
SELECT GC.id,R1.name as parent,G1.groupName as ParentGroup,R2.name as child,G2.groupName as ChildGroup
FROM groups_connected GC FULL OUTER JOIN
     Records R1 ON GC.parent_id = R1.id FULL OUTER JOIN
     GROUPS G1 ON R1.groupId = G1.id FULL OUTER JOIN
     Records R2 ON GC.child_id = R2.id FULL OUTER JOIN
     GROUPS G2 ON R2.groupId = G2.id
 WHERE G1.id = 5 OR G2.id = 5
```

Comment: this query doesn't work. i have rows in records table, but this returned empty result set :( @Raging Bull

Comment: @israr: Then change the type of `JOIN`. Updated my answer.

Comment: @israr: Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied so that it could help others in future. If you don't know how to accept one, please [**read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).